# Line breaking behaviour of unicode characters (e.g. )?

Tags: css, unicode

## Background

All the following are one line, and you should see different line-breaking behavior

#### w/equals

==========================================================================================================================================

#### w/dots

..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

#### ⚠️ w/both for reference

==============================⚠️========================================================================================================================================================================================================================

..................................⚠️................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

## Questions:

1. Why does the  break the line (while, the ⚠️ does not)?
2. On Chrome 63/Safari 11.0 why does wrapping in "=" cause the  to stay on the top line, while wrapping in "." causes the  drop down to the second line?

Recreated in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ywmrnwhu/2/) in the following container:

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  ...
}
```

Comment: for question #1: could it depend on the codepoint? the warning sign is under U+FFFF, while the unicorn is U+1F984. But I haven't verified, just an idea.

Comment: Ah yes. I wondered if it was to do with "newer" characters (not being whitelisted _or something_ in Blink/Webkit ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with the characters’ properties. [Warning Sign](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=%E2%9A%A0%EF%B8%8F&B1=Show) and [Equals Sign](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=%3D&B1=Show) are in the line break category `Alphabetic`, [Unicorn Face](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=%F0%9F%A6%84&B1=Show) is in the category `Ideographic`, and [Full Stop](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=.&B1=Show) is in the category `Infix_Numeric`.

If we consult [UAX #14: Unicode Line Breaking Algorithm](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/), we can see that [ideographic characters](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/#ID) provide line break opportunities before and after, so lines are free to break around them. Meanwhile, [alphabetic characters](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/#AL) are supposed to “stick” together, so no line breaks should occur. Since ⚠ is alphabetic, it glues to the equals signs and the line simply breaks when there is no more room to expand. The ideographic  however allows line breaks, so the text wraps as soon as it hits the unicorn to allow more space for the equals signs, which cannot break.

Now, as to why full stop behaves differently than the equals sign: [Infix numeric characters](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr14/#IS) are supposed to glue to any numeric characters that directly follow them. Since that isn’t the case here, another rule applies:

> When not used in a numeric context, infix separators are
>   sentence-ending punctuation. Therefore they always prevent breaks
>   before.

This means that the line cannot break after  since the following full stop is supposed to glue to it, so it drops down to the start of the next line instead.

Keep in mind that most of these line break categories are tailorable. They are default values that may be very useful for most applications, but can be overridden if different behaviour is more desirable. In Firefox, for example, the line breaks before  in both the full stop and the equals sign example.